# How to auto crop image region in imshow matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, imshow

I used below code to show 6 pics in a figure. However, the output contain some unwanted regions. I want to crop the image as below image. That means I want to crop it so that ROI contains the my 6 pics. Thank all

This is my code

```
%% read images in a cell array
imgs = cell(6,1);
for i=1:6
    imgs{i} = imread( sprintf('AT3_1m4_%02d.tif',i) );
end

figure(1)
spaceH=0.01;spaceV=0.06;marTop=0.3;marBot=0.08; 
 padding=0.0;margin=0.0;marginL=0.0;
yoffset = 12;
set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
% set(gcf,'color','w');
for i=1:6
    subaxis(2,3,i,'SpacingHoriz', spaceH, ...
            'SpacingVert',spaceV, 'PL',padding,'PR',padding,'mt',... 
            marTop,'mb',marBot,'ML',marginL,'MR',margin); title('Original'); 
   imshow(imgs{i},[0 255], 'InitialMag',90, 'Border','tight');
   xlb{i} = xlabel(['(' char(96+i) ')'],'FontSize', 16);
   xp = get(xlb{i}, 'position');
   xp(2) = xp(2) - yoffset; % update y-position
   set(xlb{i}, 'position', xp); % assign new position
end
```

This is my current image

[image]

I want to get output as

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34055-tightfig)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this command:

```
set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
```

You're forcing the window to a certain size.

What you could do is the following:
1. Comment out the line.
2. Execute your code.
3. Find out what size your window needs to be and scale it up.

Comment: No, I used it to zoom in my figure. After that, I will crop the unwanted region. Size of my window is unknown. It is automatically crop